# Prevent multi delays on click of identificator

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have this code:

```
$(element).on('click', function() {
    $this.closest('div').before('<span id="message" style="display:none"></span>');
    $('#message').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Where as you see, on the click of the specified element, I'm going to fade in a span#message before the div, wait 5 seconds and then fade out the span.

I tried adding stop() before the fadein but this helps only to prevent multi-animations on click, what I need is a way to prevent multi-delays on click, because an user, when try to click the specified element, will see the span fading every 5 seconds as the number of clicks on the specified element.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43z78dk6/

Comment: So is there only supposed to be one element?

Comment: I think a bigger code smell is that you are adding a new span for every click.

Comment: It's already spawning one element, the problem is that this element spawn is repeated as the number of clicks on a specified element. I need a way to detect the running delay and prevent the execution of the click handler.

Comment: Why not remove previously created spans before creating the new one?

Comment: or do not add it if it is there....

Comment: What do you mean? I need to show a message of success/error for 5 seconds and then make it disappear, I saw around that the delay function is the best way in order to do it.

Comment: Or just have it already there, invisible, and fade in/out on click

Comment: It is really unclear what your problem is..... So the code adds an element on click. The user clicks more than once so they get multiple elements. That is how it is coded. What do you want to happen when the user clicks twice? You have not explained what you want to happen so we just gave you suggestions.

Comment: My bad guys, sorry. I edited the question, missed to say that I'm trying to fade a identificator. Fiddle added: https://jsfiddle.net/43z78dk6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

If you pass in true to the `stop()`, it will jump past any queued animations, and they will be ignored.

```js
var $element = $('button');

$element.closest('div').before('<span id="elementFade" style="display:none">You clicked him!</span>');

$element.on('click', function() {
                   //pass in true to end all queued animations
                   //you can click all you want
  $('#elementFade').stop(true).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>You know you want to click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Unaware of this argument of stop function, thanks, that is the solution that I was looking for.